# Searching for records with where clause having single quotes

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, nvarchar, single-quotes

I have a table column(nvarchar type) which contains an entry "**XYZ INT'ABC**" and I am using this column in a stored procedure in the where clause. So when adding the condition in the where clause, the check should be done as below:

```
select * from tableName where ColumnName = 'XYZ INT''ABC';
```

When passing the parameter to the SP from VB.net code, the parameter is passed correctly as shown in the select query above. But the SP searches using the below query due to which I am not getting the desired output for the mentioned where clause.

```
select * from tableName where ColumnName = 'XYZ INT''''ABC';
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the VB.NET code

Comment: I am passing the correct value in the procedure parameter in the Vb.net code. But when i checked from the SQL profiler, wrong value is getting passed in the stored procedure execution statement(XYZ INT''''ABC).

Comment: In your VB code you dont need to escape single quote so your VB string should look `"XYZ INT'ABC"` , this will get doubled when being passed to sql server to escape the single quote and you will end up with `'XYZ INT''ABC'` in sql server

Comment: It seems that you pass your string with already doubled quote, pass it as it is

Comment: yes...I am converting the string from XYZ INT'ABC to XYZ INT''ABC before assigning it to the parameter value in Vb.net code. Will try the solution as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some suggestions in comments already. Just some explanation:

The doubled quotes are not really part of the string

```
DECLARE @SomeString VARCHAR(100) = 'With one quote''!';
```

The string you'll find within your variable will be `With one quote'!`. The doubled quotes are just a *syntax speciality* to allow the statement parser to see, whether a quote terminates the string or not. Something like

```
DECLARE @SomeString VARCHAR(100) = 'With one quote'!'; --wrong!
```

...is wrong, because the string ends after `quote` and the `!'` is a syntax error suddenly.

You need this only in cases, where the single quote is the string marker. In VB.Net you'd have the same issue, if you want to place a double quote `"` within your string, but this would work in SQL like here:

```
DECLARE @SomeString VARCHAR(100) = 'With one double quote"!';
```

**You must think two-folded**

- How do you assign a value? (depending on your IDE and statement parser)
- What is the actual value stored in a variable (this will be used at run-time)

**Related and more obvious example:**

Very often you see code like this (assignment)

```
string SomeString = "Some text/nwith a line-break";
```

which is translated to (actual value)

```
Some text
with a line-break
```